# I am trying To save file in Windows-1255 Encoding

Tags: javascript, npm, character-encoding, nodes, file-writing

I am using `fs.writefile` and I can't save it in ANSI1255.
The file is UTF-8 encoded.

```
  const encodedData = windows1255.encode(doc);
```

Don't work for me

Comment: Can you explain _why_ this is impossible and what you tried? Have you read the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_filehandle_writefile_data_options)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just use the optional `options.encoding` param like this?

```js
filehandle.writeFile(data, {
    encoding: 'ANSI1255' // or whatever it's called properly
});
```

If that doesn't work, this might: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53855344/7451109